# How to parse specific ID from FASTA file

Tags: text-processing

I have a [FASTA formatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) file that has a name after the ">" symbol, followed by a second line with a sequence. I would like to filter the refseqID from the name (first line), and remove the floating value. The full file has many names/sequences.

I am able to remove 'hg38_ncbiRefSeq_' from the label using the following command:

```
sed 's/hg38_ncbiRefSeq_//g' file
```

**Original format**

```
>hg38_ncbiRefSeq_NM_001276352.2 range=chr1:67093580-67127240 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none
MAEKILEKLDVLDKQAEIILARRTKINRLQSEGRKTTMAIPLTFDFQLEFEEALATSASKAISKIKEDKSCSITKSKMHVSFKCEPEPRKSNFEKSNLRPFFIQTNVKNKESESTEPVEEHLKSRSIRPYLYLKDTTEMENAGPLNVLYSQHRQACRRSLGSTDFSPMFNIQSNAHKKEKDSTLFTAQIEKKPRKPLDSVGLLEGDRNKRNKRTQIP
>hg38_ncbiRefSeq_NM_001276351.2 range=chr1:67093005-67127240 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none
MAEKILEKLDVLDKQAEIILARRTKINRLQSEGRKTTMAIPLTFDFQLEFEEALATSASKAISKIKEDKSCSITKSKMHVSFKCEPEPRKSNFEKSNLRPFFIQTNVKNKESESTAQIEKKPRKPLDSVGLLEGDRNKRKKSPQMNDFNIKENKSVRNYQLSKYRSVRKKSLLPLCFEDELKNPHAKIVNVSPTKTVTSHMEQKDTNPIIFHDTEYVRMLLLTKNRFSSHPLENENIYPHKRTNFILERNCEILKSIIGNQSISLFKPQKTMPTVQRKDIQIPMSFKAGHTTVDDKLKKKTNKQTLENRSWNTLYNFSQNFSSLTKQFVGYLDKAVIHEMSAQTGKFERMFSAGKPTSIPTSSALPVKCYSKPFKYIYELNNVTPLDNLLNLSNEILNAS
```

**Final format**

```
>NM_001276352
MAEKILEKLDVLDKQAEIILARRTKINRLQSEGRKTTMAIPLTFDFQLEFEEALATSASKAISKIKEDKSCSITKSKMHVSFKCEPEPRKSNFEKSNLRPFFIQTNVKNKESESTEPVEEHLKSRSIRPYLYLKDTTEMENAGPLNVLYSQHRQACRRSLGSTDFSPMFNIQSNAHKKEKDSTLFTAQIEKKPRKPLDSVGLLEGDRNKRNKRTQIP
>NM_001276351
MAEKILEKLDVLDKQAEIILARRTKINRLQSEGRKTTMAIPLTFDFQLEFEEALATSASKAISKIKEDKSCSITKSKMHVSFKCEPEPRKSNFEKSNLRPFFIQTNVKNKESESTAQIEKKPRKPLDSVGLLEGDRNKRKKSPQMNDFNIKENKSVRNYQLSKYRSVRKKSLLPLCFEDELKNPHAKIVNVSPTKTVTSHMEQKDTNPIIFHDTEYVRMLLLTKNRFSSHPLENENIYPHKRTNFILERNCEILKSIIGNQSISLFKPQKTMPTVQRKDIQIPMSFKAGHTTVDDKLKKKTNKQTLENRSWNTLYNFSQNFSSLTKQFVGYLDKAVIHEMSAQTGKFERMFSAGKPTSIPTSSALPVKCYSKPFKYIYELNNVTPLDNLLNLSNEILNAS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like with `awk`:

```
awk -F'[ _.]' '{if ($0~"^>") print ">"$3"_"$4; else print $0}' input_file
```

You can use shorter form as sugested in a previous comment by [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton):

```
awk -F'[ _.]' '{print (/^>/ ? ">"$3"_"$4 : $0)}' input_file
```